# How to get data from a device connected in a local network to my application

Tags: php, networking, tcp, php-socket

I am trying to get data from a device which is connected in the local network.

The device listens to 192.168.1.2:10000 
For example we can call the function getItems() on the windows computer in the network and we get all the items.

Now I want to do this in my cloud application (php). So I want that example.com/getItems get the items from the device.

I am a noob at networking, so I hope someone can give some advice how to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at least you need to open your local firewall and expose the Port 10000 and NAT it to you local 192.168.1.2:10000 to the public internet.

If there are no further IPv6 restrictions and you have a static IPv6 address you can reach that it from the cloud php.
If you have a typical private internet access, consider to use a dynDNS or similar service to reach you changing IP by a static FQDN.

Comment: Are there security risk involved. I think that everyone can access this ip address, right? How can I avoid this?

Comment: this depends on your device's capabilites to filter on e.g. source IPs. this could be done either bei your device and/or also by your router's firewall.